# Master/Slave mysql Error replication a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I have some issues regarding the **DB Master/Slave out of sync**, it's been 10 days when the issue started and everyday i tried manually to sync those DB by skipping the error

```
==="Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" ===

mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.1
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: Secondary2-mysql-bin.000019
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 444543195
               Relay_Log_File: Hostname1-relay-bin.002176
                Relay_Log_Pos: 435496347
        Relay_Master_Log_File: Secondary2-mysql-bin.000019
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: ipcr_db
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: table=test_db.log,test_db.heartbeats
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1452
                   Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_db`.`column2`, CONSTRAINT `column3` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_id`) REFERENCES `parts` (`part_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON)' on query. Default database: 'test_db'. 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 435496173
              Relay_Log_Space: 444543605
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1452
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_db`.`column2`, CONSTRAINT `column2` FOREIGN KEY (`part`) REFERENCES `part` (`part`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON)' on query. Default database: 'test_db'. 
             Master_Server_Id: 2
                  Master_UUID: 4642e16c-2050-11e5-a03c-000c29859f45
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 170727 08:18:41
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

..but skipping the error , data from Master will not be sent towards Slave so in the end I inserting manualy the missing data from master to slave, to have the same data and to be correctly synced.

To skip the error or to correct **Read_Master_Log_Pos:** with  **Exec_Master_Log_Pos** I am typing:

```
mysql> stop slave; SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; start slave;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

If anyone db expert can help me i would appreciate this a lot.

Regards,

Comment: Please check ENGINE of table is same (InnoDB) on both nodes master and slave. Ideally it should also throw error on master node when you doing changes in child table and it doesn't exist in parent table.